# Program compiled by gcc runs faster than compiled by g++

Tags: c, performance, gcc, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance difference between gcc and g++ for C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302657/performance-difference-between-gcc-and-g-for-c-program)

I was checking the improvement of performance with using register storage specifier for the loop control variable when I accidentally noticed that program compiled with gcc runs faster than compiled with g++. Can someone explain it to me?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned long scope = 1000000000;

int main()
{
    register unsigned long i;
    for (i=0; i < scope; i++);
    return 0;
}
```

;

```
gcc register.c
time ./a.out   
real    0m0.466s
user    0m0.468s
sys     0m0.000s

g++ register.c
time ./a.out 
real    0m0.923s
user    0m0.920s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Look at the disassembly.

Comment: Optimization level difference probably.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your results on my hardware.  Which gcc release are you using?

Comment: [Performance difference between gcc and g++ for C program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302657/performance-difference-between-gcc-and-g-for-c-program)

Comment: @KingsIndian thanks for that you pointed this question to downvote the accepted answer because this difference exist

Comment: I'm sorry I was searching the forum and didn't find it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @memosdp Well there are better answers and comments explaining why. This question is basically the same as that one but with a snippet of code. I didn't want/expect anyone to downvote the accepted answer. It's your choice :)

Comment: @KingsIndian of course ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the behaviour (gcc-4.6.2), the relevant parts of the produced assembly are

C:

```
.L3:
    addq    $1, %rbx
.L2:
    movq    scope(%rip), %rax
    cmpq    %rax, %rbx
    jb      .L3
```

C++:

```
.L3:
    addq    $1, %rbx
.L2:
    cmpq     $999999999, %rbx
    setbe    %al
    testb    %al, %al
    jne      .L3
```

so the C compiler produced a better loop test. Don't ask me why, I have no idea.

Comment: Because in C++ `const` is a constant expression, just like writing the value inline, and the code gets compiled as such. In C, `const` is an immutable variable, and since it has external linkage, gcc generated it and generated an actual access to it. This *could* be avoided, but detecting the conditions under which it could be avoided is not entirely trivial.

Comment: In any case, I have no idea why g++ generated the idiotic `setbe`/`testb` sequence for doing the comparison. That's probably a bug in your version of gcc. If it had generated the right code for the way it's treating the C++, the C++ version would be the same speed or faster.

Comment: @R.. Not a 'bug' in gcc, but certainly not the best code. Am I missing something, or is everybody not turning on optimization? The loop should be completely eliminated by the optimizer, since it doesn't do anything. If you don't turn on the optimizer, you don't get to complain about the code, and timing is for amusement only.

Answer (score 1):

While I couldn't get the same results on my i5 M520 (`gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`), I did see differences in the disassembled output.

```
$ sdiff f.S  f_cpp.S 
...
00000000004004b4 <main>:                                        00000000004004b4 <main>:
  4004b4:       55                      push   %rbp               4004b4:       55                      push   %rbp
  4004b5:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp          4004b5:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004b8:       53                      push   %rbx               4004b8:       53                      push   %rbx
  4004b9:       bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx          4004b9:       bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
  4004be:       eb 04                   jmp    4004c4 <main+0     4004be:       eb 04                   jmp    4004c4 <main+0
  4004c0:       48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx          4004c0:       48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx
  4004c4:       48 8b 05 05 01 00 00    mov    0x105(%rip),%r |   4004c4:       48 81 fb ff c9 9a 3b    cmp    $0x3b9ac9ff,%r
  4004cb:       48 39 c3                cmp    %rax,%rbx      |   4004cb:       0f 96 c0                setbe  %al
  4004ce:       72 f0                   jb     4004c0 <main+0 |   4004ce:       84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  4004d0:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax      |   4004d0:       75 ee                   jne    4004c0 <main+0
  4004d5:       5b                      pop    %rbx           |   4004d2:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4004d6:       5d                      pop    %rbp           |   4004d7:       5b                      pop    %rbx
  4004d7:       c3                      retq                  |   4004d8:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004d8:       90                      nop                   |   4004d9:       c3                      retq   
  4004d9:       90                      nop                   <
  4004da:       90                      nop                       4004da:       90                      nop
  4004db:       90                      nop                       4004db:       90                      nop
```

And here's how the gcc/C one went when profiled:

```
 Percent |  Source code & Disassembly of f_c
------------------------------------------------
         :
         :
         :
         :  Disassembly of section .text:
         :
         :  00000000004004b4 <main>:
    0.00 :    4004b4:       push   %rbp
    0.00 :    4004b5:       mov    %rsp,%rbp
    0.00 :    4004b8:       push   %rbx
    0.00 :    4004b9:       mov    $0x0,%ebx
    0.00 :    4004be:       jmp    4004c4 <main+0x10>
   48.97 :    4004c0:       add    $0x1,%rbx
    0.00 :    4004c4:       mov    0x105(%rip),%rax        # 4005d0 <scope>
   51.03 :    4004cb:       cmp    %rax,%rbx
    0.00 :    4004ce:       jb     4004c0 <main+0xc>
    0.00 :    4004d0:       mov    $0x0,%eax
    0.00 :    4004d5:       pop    %rbx
    0.00 :    4004d6:       pop    %rbp
```

And here's how the g++ one went when profiled:

```
 Percent |  Source code & Disassembly of g_cpp
------------------------------------------------
         :
         :
         :
         :  Disassembly of section .text:
         :
         :  00000000004004b4 <main>:
    0.00 :    4004b4:       push   %rbp
    0.00 :    4004b5:       mov    %rsp,%rbp
    0.00 :    4004b8:       push   %rbx
    0.00 :    4004b9:       mov    $0x0,%ebx
    0.00 :    4004be:       jmp    4004c4 <main+0x10>
   49.49 :    4004c0:       add    $0x1,%rbx
    0.00 :    4004c4:       cmp    $0x3b9ac9ff,%rbx
   11.24 :    4004cb:       setbe  %al
   39.27 :    4004ce:       test   %al,%al
    0.00 :    4004d0:       jne    4004c0 <main+0xc>
    0.00 :    4004d2:       mov    $0x0,%eax
    0.00 :    4004d7:       pop    %rbx
    0.00 :    4004d8:       pop    %rbp
```